# Выезжающий элемент при наведении курсора

Tags: css

Есть сайт http://www.xn--80ajbnhehmdihidodj.xn--p1ai/. У них в слайдере, при наведении курсора на иконку >, появляется выезжающий текст ("Перейти"). Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.block').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.arrow span:first-child').stop(true).toggle('fadeIn');
});


$('.blocks .block').hover(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'background-position':  'no-repeat',
    'background-size':      'cover',
    'background-image':     'url(' + $(this).parent().data('background') + ')'
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.block .title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    z-index: 11;
    position: relative;
}

.block .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    z-index: 11;
}

.block {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: block !important;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: none;
}

.block:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.blue-dark {
    background-color: #47bdfb !important;
}

.block .arrow span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.block .arrow span:last-child {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAkCAYAAAERNkEIAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAyZpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuNi1jMDE0IDc5LjE1Njc5NywgMjAxNC8wOC8yMC0wOTo1MzowMiAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIDIwMTQgKFdpbmRvd3MpIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjEzQjAyRTE4ODIxQjExRTVBRUQ1RDlGNzYyQTBDRDhDIiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjEzQjAyRTE5ODIxQjExRTVBRUQ1RDlGNzYyQTBDRDhDIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6MTNCMDJFMTY4MjFCMTFFNUFFRDVEOUY3NjJBMENEOEMiIHN0UmVmOmRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6MTNCMDJFMTc4MjFCMTFFNUFFRDVEOUY3NjJBMENEOEMiLz4gPC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+IDwvcmRmOlJERj4gPC94OnhtcG1ldGE+IDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9InIiPz7n18biAAABoUlEQVR42mL8//8/AwwwQen/yBxGkACMIwQSYATqAQn8A4kABBAjNgNwc+BG/4cazQAQQDAD4ALoWhiRtWIYDATCcEmQUUAs+B8CYHwGgABCcSSyMWeB+Ci6oDEQcyBLwCxEkUA3E2TUD3RBEIefAckpIMAHVoQuABNEEQBhgACCMf4A8VFkCWwY5lQWqFP/o3sQVwwZQ0MapyYmLAbg1IQ1wJEAKB29hTmVCY+i/1CF/FCb/rLgMQmk6BOyJEyxIBC/w6UIXbEbPkUwABBAMA/C8wG+MI4AORyI+fApRE64GGkAW3ogqBiZI4RPMbpOnIqxuQerYlzpE0MxvoSCGrUEUv5ZqKlHiFF0FJ8bURThUoihCJtCrIrQFcIdji8K8SqCKTxFSBGyiQcJlSQAAYbMiQDiQ/jSJLEYRDAhOfU/UgjxUWIocqY4Sw3DsQlSbDg+SSFyDSfGZpINJyWsiDacnNglaDgl6RGb4aDcw0xNA4+iV/lUDVeqRxIxhpKVVkmNBD5ycpQgJYZhq2EpNgzd0AhoU44iw3A1bAk2R4gBACTDAKPlJ1oMAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat;
    height: 36px;
    width: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
}


.block .arrow span:first-child {
    display: none;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 71px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
  <div class="container blocks">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-background="http://www.xn--80ajbnhehmdihidodj.xn--p1ai/upload/iblock/adc/adc46d8ff59ae9e6660272df9b76db90.jpg">
        <a href="#" class="block blue-dark">
          <div class="title">Профнастил</div>
          
          <span class="arrow">
            <span>Перейти</span>
            <span></span>
          </span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Отдельно стрелка, реализованная как на сайте через js:

```js
$('a').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.arrow span:first-child').stop(true).toggle('fadeIn');
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:24px;
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.arrow span:last-child {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat;
    height: 36px;
    width: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.arrow span:first-child {
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<a href="#">
  <span class="arrow">
    <span>Перейти</span>
    <span>  </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

А вот вариант реализации только с помощью стилей, анимация ширины:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:24px;
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}

.arrow span:last-child {
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat;
    height: 36px;
    width: 21px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.arrow span:first-child {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
  
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  
}

a:hover span:first-child {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="arrow">
    <span>Перейти</span>
    <span>  </span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Немало вариантов конечно=)) (+)

Comment: @Arthur, это точно вариантом с помощью одного только css уйма, привела только один ) Как раз может быть кто-то еще предложит решения.